# Is it possible to temporarily disable all notifications on Android wear?

Tags: android-wear

I was looking into getting an android wear device but I will need to make it just a watch without the smart bit sometimes. Is there a quick and easy way of doing this?

I was looking at the Sony smartwatch 3 but I am not definite as to which one to get.

Comment: Why buy a SMART Watch and remove the SMART part?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab My school will not let me have it in lessons unless I can make it a normal watch temporarily.

Comment: ah OK:-), I don't think it is possible except for shutting down your watch. Sorry to tell you but that's why its a Smart Watch.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab OK thanks! Is there an app i can get or a setting? I guess that kind of makes sense...

Comment: You can disable the notifications if you put your watch on silent mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the notifications on your wearable device by following steps below:

1. Swipe down from the watchface
2. You should see something like this:
   [image]
3. Select the option on the left will put your watch to silent mode.

Hope my answer helps.

Comment: That looks like it works! Thanks! I'll say for definate when I get smartwatch!